# How to convert a location from watcher of Window phone 7 to location of google map

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, google-maps

Actually, i am working with google map on window phone 7.
I am trying to convert location of watcher of window phone 7 to location of google map.
 with :
lat = "47.6818256764486"
lng = "-122.064292703125"

**C#  using watcher in library System.Device.Location**

```
void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {

        String lat = "" + e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        String lng = "" + e.Position.Location.Longitude;

        Browser.InvokeScript("Marker_up", lat, lng);
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
 function Marker_up(lat,lng) {

     var Lat = Number(lat);
     var Lng = Number(lng);   
     var New_lc = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: New_lc,
                map: map
            });
           marker.setmap(map);
           map.setCenter(New_lc);
  }
```

But it can't. I don't know why.
Please someone help me.

Comment: How to improve please?? iam new here. Please forgive me.

Comment: Excuse me.Do u know about my case?? I am really do not know why.Please help me. I am new with Javascript. In C#, i passed 2 strings to Javascript, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set `IsScriptEnabled = true` on the browser, scripts won't work.

[WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)